# Why doesn't rustc infer the type based on std trait implementations?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, type-inference

Consider the following code:

```rust
use std::net::IpAddr;

pub struct Server {
    host: IpAddr
}

impl Server {
    fn new(host: IpAddr) -> Self {
        Self {host}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let host = "192.168.0.1".parse().unwrap();
    let server = Server::new(host.clone());
}
```

`rustc` complains that it cannot infer the type of `host`, and that type annotations are needed in its definition.

Due to the method signature of `Server::new()`, (`fn new(host: IpAddr) -> Self`), Rust can conclude that the type of the expression `host.clone()` must be `IpAddr`. I can understand that `rustc` can't be certain of the type of `host` based on this alone because any type can implement a method named `clone()` returning an `IpAddr`, but given that `rustc` can't find any other types that implement a `clone()` method which returns `IpAddr`, is it a bridge too far for `rustc` to assume that that `host` is a type that implements [std::clone::Clone](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#), and returns an `IpAddr` and therefore must be an `IpAddr` itself? What is the danger of such assumption that motivated the design of `rustc` to fail to compile this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`host.clone()` is opaque to the type inference algorithm until it knows what `host` is, because what `host.clone()` means depends on it.

This could only work if it was entirely unambiguous, and adding a new type with a `clone()` method would be sufficient to make it ambiguous:

```
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    pub fn clone(&self) -> IpAddr { unimplemented!(); }
}

impl FromStr for Foo {
    type Err = ();
    fn from_str(_s: &str) -> Result<Foo, ()> { unimplemented!(); }
}
```

And this is even before we add in things like auto-deref, which means `host` could theoretically be some type implementing `Deref<Target=IpAddr>` as well.

Adding a new type to your program should never break type inference, but if the compiler looked around to see what `host.clone()` could be before it knows what `host` is, that's exactly what could happen.

If rustc did this, it would be useful in very few cases, and in those it would be very fragile.

Comment: So the benefit of guaranteeing that the addition of a new type cannot disambiguate existing type inferences is worth the cost of the inconvenience of disallowing such existing type inferences in the first place?

Comment: @RBF06 It's not just that -- the cost of implementing this kind of inference would be pretty high. The compiler would have to search all methods of all types and traits currently in scope to find those that match the call signature. Then it has to take into account for things like auto-deref of `host`. Basically, it would be a huge amount of work for inference that would almost always be ambiguous and would be easy to cause to fail later.

Comment: @RBF06 As an example of the kind of complexity I'm talking about, the compiler would have to consider that `host` could be _any_ type implementing `Deref<Target=IpAddr>` that itself doesn't have a `clone()` method. Then `host.clone()` would auto-deref `host` and call `IpAddr`s `clone()` method, but `host` itself wouldn't have to be `IpAddr`.